# Will Heroic trigger if a spell would cause the creature to lose all abilities?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-heroic

So me and a buddy of mine got into a argument: he had [Setessan Battle Priest](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Setessan%20Battle%20Priest) out which has heroic

> Whenever you cast a spell that targets Setessan Battle Priest, you gain 2 life

Then he played [Turn to Frog](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Turn%20to%20Frog), which takes all abilities away and makes it a 1/1 Blue Frog until end of turn. He said he gained two life because Heroic triggers from the spell. I said that it took away the ability so it doesn't activate. Who was right?

Comment: At the bottom of the page you linked for Setessan Battle Priest, it states `"Heroic abilities will resolve before the spell that caused them to trigger."`

Answer (score 12):

Yes, Heroic does trigger in that situation, and he does gain the 2 life. This is because Heroic triggers when you *cast* the spell, before it resolves and has any effects. Basically, it plays out like this:

1. Your opponent casts Turn to Frog targeting his Setessan Battle Priest. The Priest's Heroic ability triggers. Now there are two objects on the stack: the Heroic ability is on top of the Turn to Frog spell.
2. The Heroic ability resolves, and your opponent gains 2 life.
3. Turn to Frog resolves and the Priest loses all of its abilities.

The rulings on Setessan Battle Priest's Gatherer page also mention this:

> Heroic abilities will resolve before the spell that caused them to trigger.